# Use Wkhtmltopdf on Laradock

Tags: laravel-5, wkhtmltopdf, laradock

I have downloaded **Laradock**.
Now I want use **WKHTMLTOPDF** and I have installed in my app Snappy and https://github.com/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 for the binary.

But if I try for example:

> ./wkhtmltopdf-amd64 http://google.com google.pdf

I receive this error:

> QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_num_locks 10%
>
> QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_id_callback
>
> QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
>
> QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_free
>
> QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_num QSslSocket: cannot resolve
> sk_pop_free
>
> QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_value
>
> QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_library_init
>
> QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_load_error_strings
>
> QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_client_method
>
> QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv23_client_method
>
> QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_server_method
>
> QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv23_server_method
>
> QSslSocket: cannot resolve X509_STORE_CTX_get_chain
>
> QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf
>
> QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_conf
>
> QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLeay
>
> QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_num_locks
>
> QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_id_callback
>
> QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function
> CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
>
> QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
>
> QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
>
> QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function sk_num
>
> QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method7%
>
> QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init Warning:
> Failed to load
>
> CRYPTO_num_locks QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function
>
> CRYPTO_set_id_callback QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function
>
> CRYPTO_set_locking_callbac

I've read that I've to install this package **libssl1.0-dev** but when I try to install in laradock I receive:

> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> Package libssl1.0-dev is not available, but is referred to by another
> package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been
> obsoleted, or is only available from another source
>
> E: Package 'libssl1.0-dev' has no installation candidate

How can I use wkhtmltopdf on Laradock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved with a wkhtmltopdf version 12.5.

Seems that this bug exists on version 12.4.